# Redux State is set also to other State that is not Related

Tags: redux

Programming is weird, if you think not then check this case , I'm using createSlices as Redux and I have two slices with their own states.

First one is `orderSlice`:

```js
export const orderSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'order',
  initialState: {
    order: null,
    message: null,
    isLoading: true,
  }
})
```

While the second slice is `ordersSlice`:

```js
export const orderSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'orders',
  initialState: {
    orders: null,
    message: null,
    isLoading: true,
  }
})
```

And I have this method to fetch the order and the fulfilled phase where the state is set from:

Fetching the order:

```js
export const fetchOrder = createAsyncThunk('', async ({ token, id }) => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${api}/orders/view/${id}`, requestOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Filling the order state:

```js
extraReducers: {
    [fetchOrder.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.order = action.payload.data;
      state.message = 'Succesfully fetched the Order.';
      state.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

While here is method for fetching the orders:

```js
export const fetchAllOrders = createAsyncThunk('', async (token) => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${api}/orders/all`, requestOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

And here updating the orders state:

```js
extraReducers: {
    [fetchAllOrders.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.orders = action.payload.data;
      state.message = 'Succesfully fetched all Orders.';
      state.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

So the case is that I'm calling the fetchAllOrders in the Order page with UseEffect, here is how:

```js
  import { fetchAllOrders } from '../redux/ordersSlice';
  useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchAllOrders(user.token)), [user]);
```

So this is how i run the method to fetch orders with dispatch and it works. But the problem is that when I run this function beside the `orders` state that is filled with the same data, also the `order` state is filled with the same data and this is impossible as I've cheked all the cases where I could misstyped a user,users typo but there is none I found, and I don't know.

And here is the store:

```js
import orderSlice from './redux/orderSlice';
import ordersSlice from './redux/ordersSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    order: orderSlice,
    orders: ordersSlice
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give your thunks an unique name: If you name both `''` they will be handled interchangably.

Also, you should be using the [builder notation for extraReducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation). We will deprecate the object notation you are using soon.

Comment: This is deep, thanks.

Comment: can you explain the purpose of links in thunks we don't use them anywhere, in my case I'm using api inside the function, also for the best practices.

Comment: what do you mean by links in thunks?

Comment: I mean this `createAsyncThunk('', async (token)...)`, the `' '` what they are for

Comment: They are the name of the thunk. They will be used to derive the name of the thunk actions, like `thunkName/fulfilled` and `thunkName/pending`. In your case all your names are an empty string, so all your thunk actions are just `/fulfilled` and `/pending`, so the extraReducers will all always match any thunk. Every single one of your asyncThunks needs a name that is unique for your whole app.

Comment: Very clear thank you